# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function _main

Tags: opengl, windows, visual-studio

I try this code from tutorial for learn Modern OpenGL in Visual Studio 2015:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

With GLUT (from other tutorial), it workink fine (other project with glew32.lib and freeglut.lib).
With GLEW Project after add glew32.lib and glfw3.lib, lesson 2 has problem in: glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

It return linking error in compiling:
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_ glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function _main

This code:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW. Always include it before gl.h and glfw.h, since it's a bit magic.
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main()
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); //We don't want the old OpenGL 

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window; // (In the accompanying source code, this variable is global)

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed in core profile

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    do {
        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
            );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    } while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not adding `glew32.lib` properly (check the paths), you can also use `pragma comment(lib,"glew32.lib")` in the source file add the library.

Comment: I check the paths and try '#pragme comment(lib,"glew32.lib")' and still return same LNK errors.